# What is the name of this particular indent style? ("braces stacked")

Tags: coding-style, indentation, braces

I've seen this questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159366/is-there-a-best-coding-style-for-identations-same-line-next-line).
I'm wondering if there exists an official name for the following indent style:

```
void fooBar(String s)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // ... do something
    }
}
```

When the opening brace is in the same line as the control statement, the statements within are indented and the closing brace is on the same indentation level as the control statement, the style is called K&R-Style.
So is there a name for the indent style for the this code sample above?

Comment: I'm not quite sure that the description you gave matches up to the example code.

Comment: The description talks about K&R-style (or "the only sane bracketing scheme" if you ask me)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Allman style (bsd in Emacs) see wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Answer (score 3):

Yep, this is the ANSI style, called this way because it appears in the ANSI C documents. The popular auto-formatting util [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html) refers to it as `ansi`

AFAIK, It's also the one used by default in Visual C++.

Answer (score -1):

It's called [KNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KNF) or Kernel Normal Form.  More information can be found in [man 9 style](http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/cgi/web-man?command=style&section=9).

Comment: KNF use 8 space wide hard tabs, Allman/ANSI uses 4 space wide soft tabs (spaces).

Answer (score -7):

It should be named WSRE (Waste of Screen Real Estate).

Comment: Or LIS - Legibility Improving Style.